# Form submit with upload file and input type text at a time

Tags: java

Form submit with upload file and input type text at a time, can we get both items in servlet and can do any operations? I have used multipart/form-data also. But I am unable to get text data, its getting null. I want to store text data and upload file same time in servlet.

Comment: A little more info and some code would be nice.

Comment: Generally, yes you can. Show your code.

Comment: <form action="uploadDownloadFileServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Sow Id" name="sowIdTextBox"  id="sowIdTextBox" required="required">
<input type = "file" id="fileName" name="fileName">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Comment: String sowIdTextBox = request.getParameter("sowIdTextBox");
System.out.println(sowIdTextBox);
List<FileItem> fileItemsList = uploader.parseRequest(request);
Iterator<FileItem> fileItemsIterator = fileItemsList.iterator();
while (fileItemsIterator.hasNext())
{
 FileItem fileItem = fileItemsIterator.next();
 File file = new File(getServletContext().getAttribute("FILES_DIR")+ File.separator + fileItem.getName());
 System.out.println("Absolute Path at server=" + file.getAbsolutePath());
 fileItem.write(file); }

Comment: 1st one ins jsp, 2nd one is servlet. Its printing null in console for "System.out.println(sowIdTextBox);". I am able to upload file into one location, but text box value am getting as null. That is my problem.

Comment: Don't add code in comments, [edit] your question.

Comment: Then how can I show the code, I am new to stackoverflow account

Comment: There is an [edit] link below your question, use it.